# Excel - How to chart on part of table depending on given criteria

Tags: excel

I have a table (named ABC) with many cols and rows. One column is named 'ID'. There is another range with all unique values of ID column (Let's say 5 unique IDs).

Now I want to make 5 charts, each for an ID. The chart will be based on those rows in the table with ID column = .

Is there a good way to achieve this?

Comment: Make a range that holds each chart's data and point the chart at that. There is no other reasonable way to approach this. Perhaps if you can share how your data looks and an example of the chart we can guide you towards the creation of the ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to store another range with the unique values. Just create a PivotChart and set the ID column as the Report Filter. The Report Filter on the PivotChart will show you the unique values and you can pick which one you want to look at. Having just one report where you can switch between the filter values is the best way of doing this, so that if you ever want to change any of the formatting, you only have to change 1 chart instead of 5 charts.

Select your table, then click Insert > PivotChart (it may be under the PivotTable button depending on Excel version).

Design your PivotChart similar to how you would design a PivotTable, dragging fields to the different areas.

The field with the categories to go along the bottom axis (x-axis) go into the Axis Fields area.

The field with the data to be summed or counted goes into the Values section. (If there's only one value for each category in your data that you want displayed, then group by summing the values)

If there is more than one series to be charted, then put the field that defines the different series into the Legend Fields section.

The ID column goes into the Report Filter section. You choose the values to filter on the PivotChart itself.

When the PivotChart is selected, the PivotChart Tools ribbon appears. Use the Design tab to change the Chart Type and colour scheme.